# Will a tourist have any trouble getting money from an ATM India because of demonetization?

Tags: india, money, atms

I will be travelling to India as a tourist at the end of this month. I have heard about long lines at banks, and I was wondering whether I would have any trouble getting money from an ATM as a tourist. (I would certainly prefer the convenience of an ATM to carrying around U.S. dollars to change.)

Comment: Traveller's cheques?

Comment: @Mawg - Traveler Checks are falling out of favor with travelers and banks alike, with American Express being about the only one that is accepted universally.  There has been too much trouble with counterfeits.

Comment: Can anyone explain what "demonetization" is? Googling might find it (I haven't checked yet), but this seems like something that should be in the question, as it's hardly common knowledge.

Comment: We're now toward the end of this trip, and I offer the following comments: all ATMs either have long lines or are out of cash. Bringing USD was the easiest way to get money. Better rates were available in Paharganj (a touristy area) than in the airport. So a reasonable recommendation is to use the airport for a minimal exchange (e.g., taxi fare to your destination) and then do a proper conversion once you're there. (The difference is a couple of dollars when you change 100 USD.)

Answer (score 20, accepted):

ATM withdrawals will be capped, so you will only be able to withdraw around INR 2500 ($36 US) a day from an ATM. (This limit might change - as Andrew says, the situation is fluid). Additionally, each withdrawal using a foreign card can have around a $7 fee.

Depending on your timing and the area, ATMs might have a queue, on average around 20 people.
Moreover, the ATM might give you one note of INR 2000, which you would have difficulty finding change for.

- Use your credit card as much as possible to pay ahead of time.
- Download and use taxi apps like Uber, Ola and Meru.
- Paytm is a popularly accepted payment app, but it does not accept foreign cards. Perhaps a friend can load one up for you with up to Rs 10,000.

There are other ways to get cash as well - sending it to yourself online via Western Union for one. Try and avoid using local 'fixers' or touts who offer to change cash for you.

---

Update: As of late January 2017, the situation has mostly normalized. The withdrawal limit at ATMs is now at Rs. 10,000 a day and 24,000 a week, and the only other inconvenience is finding change for the high-denomination Rs 2000 note.

Comment: I forgot to mention the fee, because my bank refunds it as a matter of course. But it was the highest I had seen world-wide on a percentage basis.

Comment: Does Uber work without paytm?

Comment: Can you sign up to Ola or Meru without a local number?

Comment: @ksav IIRC you can add a credit card directly to Uber without using Paytm.

Comment: I've heard many (small) vendors are temporarily refusing payments by card since they need cash. Is that still true?

Comment: @JonathanReez  not at all.

Comment: Does the limitation of INR 2500 apply to each ATM, or (somehow) to the entire country? (Once in America I needed a lot of cash and I just went to several ATMs on the same day.)

Comment: Why try to avoid touts?

Comment: @adam.baker Restrictions apply to an "account" as seen by an Indian bank, in addition to per ATM withdrawal. But to be honest the government is playing it by ear, and your foreign card may be able to withdraw multiple times, as mentioned by fiksdal. Banks and ATM management companies are working round the clock to keep their IT systems in sync with the new rules, so if abused, this method might not work in coming weeks.

Comment: The current ATM limit has been raised to ₹10,000. I pulled this much successfully a few days ago. Paytm does accept foreign cards, at least American Express, which I've been using.

Comment: I have not had any trouble getting cash while traveling for the last month in Delhi, Jaipur, Agra, Rishikesh, Varanasi, and Kochi. Just ask a rickshaw driver to bring you to the nearest working ATM machine. I've had to wait 5 minutes at most. Here in Kochi, there is usually no line (my local ATM gives 5 bills of ₹2000 if I request ₹10000, or 19 bills of ₹500 if I request ₹9500.

Answer (score 8):

Uber works very well in India and you can use the card you already have connected to the app, but it will charge in rupees. I recommend using Uber, most of the time its actually cheaper than what Autos will charge a foreigner, and I have been ripped off by Ola drivers. Just make sure that your phone will work in India (T-mobile is great FYI). I would also recommend, bringing a credit card and debit card that don't charge foreign transaction/withdrawal fees, as these add up fast. There are many places that are still affordable (hotels, fancier restaurants) that accept cards.

I lived in India this summer and had a very easy time using surprisingly little cash. As for the limits on the ATMs, you will probably just need to go to an ATM once ever day or two depending on your cash expenditure. Clearly, finding one that can provide will be a struggle though.

Also it is not recommended to carry around USD to exchange as exchange rates are fluid and it is easy to get very ripped off. Not a smart way to travel. There are some countries (Mongolia for example) that will take foreign currencies (USD and RMB) at a better for you exchange rate instead of local currency. They are willing to do this because they can use the foreign currency there as well. I have not found that India is not one of these countries and especially now, exchanging money is even more costly for people and they will be inclined to charge you more the "service".

I was planning a trip there for the holidays to see family and scratched it... if possible probably a good idea if you are going purely as a tourist. If you do go, travel smart, get cards with no foreign fees and use a cell phone plan that will cover you abroad. Maybe expand your budget a bit to cover "emergency meals" at nicer restaurants with you cards.

Answer (score 8):

Go into a bank and get a cash advance on your Visa or MasterCard debit card.  You can do the same from a credit card, but they charge interest from the moment you get the cash (so 1 to 2% if you pay the card off right away).

The advantage of a cash advance is you can get more than what ATMs will dispense, but the exchange rate will be determined by your bank at home same a purchase would be so you won't get what the India bank has posted.

You will need your passport with you when you go to the bank.  And not all banks will offer Visa or MasterCard cash advances, you may have to ask around.

Comment: Whether you pay interest on cash advances depends on the contract you have with your credit card provider. Mine does charge high fees but does not charge interest as long as I pay at the end of the month and then it falls under the same interest level as all payments.

Comment: @Willeke  You may be quite lucky as all cards I have ever had or considered getting treated cash advances as interest bearing immediately.  Perhaps you can reveal this interest free cash advance card so that other travelers may benefit.

Comment: It was in the contract I had with the Dutch bank Postbank, now fused with ING. I am not even sure what the current rules are as I never have a cash advance these days. (Due to the high cost.)

Answer (score 8):

Yes, you will have a lot of trouble.

For starters, there's an officially imposed cap of about INR 2000 on ATM Withdrawals per day.  Now, given the fact that INR 2000 is barely USD 30,  you can easily imagine that amount won't get you too far in a day. Especially as a foreign tourist.

Now, add to this the fact that anecdotally, about 9 out of every 10 ATM machines I see on the street today are "Out of Action".

And the few ATMs that do have cash have an average queue of anywhere from 20 to 50 people in front of them.

Travellers checks etc. aren't of much use either because the banks are themselves low on cash. So expect difficulties there too. What's worse is that most ATMs and banks too are issuing INR 2000 denominations which are unwieldy to use for most purposes or to get change for.

In my opinion your best bet is:

- Minimize the use of cash. Use debit / credit cards for most high value purchases
- Try to get money changed at Cash Bureau during your travel or before you land in India if that's an option
- For small transactions try to go for Ola / Uber etc to avoid wasting your cash on taxis etc
- Use cash as a last resort only where you really must.
- Proactively think through what your major expenses will be and try to plan so that as many as possible can be eliminated from cash to electronic. e.g. Buy Rail tickets online, hire online cabs etc.
- Try your hotel desk for cash exchange. They might save you the hassle of other options.

Answer (score 7):

The situation is fluid. I was there two weeks ago. On arrival I used the ATM at the upscale hotel (no line), but by the end of my stay it was empty. The site I was working at had its own ATM, with a block-long line, and it always ran out before everyone got there.

The only ATMs I would expect to be stocked are airside, and I am not sure there are any such. The landside ones at BOM were also empty.

Comment: What is BOM? Airside? Landside?

Comment: BOM is the airport for Mumbai (formerly Bombay). I think you will find 3-letter codes here are usually airports. Landside and airside refer to the part of the airport before or after security, so landside is accessible to non-passengers; airside is not.

Welcome to Travel.se. I think you will find these terms in general use here.

Comment: and ATM is the airport for Altamira, Brazil. HTH :)

Comment: And HTH is the code for Hawthorne Industrial Airport in Nevada. YMW ;-)

Comment: and YMW is the code for Maniwaki Airport in Quebec, Canada. FYI :)

Answer (score 7):

There are long lines and a lot of ATMs are closed. Also, there is currently a limit of 2000 per card per ATM per day. However, the other day my friend with a German card was able to make eight withdrawals at one ATM in five minutes with a single card and thus get 16.000. As for why that was possible, I can only speculate that the limit system didn't work for foreign cards. It's difficult to predict all this, though, everything is always changing.

> I would certainly prefer the convenience of an ATM to carrying around U.S. dollars to change.

I recommend you bring a fair amount of dollars just in case. ATMs are  extremely unreliable right now, and you want your eggs in as many baskets as possible.

The way it is now, I'd bring a decent amount and guard it carefully. The ATM situation is pretty terrible these days.

Comment: Some dollars, certainly, but the question here is if you're planning to spend for example around $2000 during the journey, what's the best strategy to minimize the overall risks of robbery versus getting stuck without money.

Comment: @downhand The way it is now, I'd bring a decent amount and guard it carefully. The ATM situation is pretty terrible these days.

Comment: Is this a recent problem in India or does that concern other Asian countries too?

Comment: @downhand Only India. More details here: http://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/82198/india-just-demonetized-all-rs-500-1000-notes-what-do-i-do-with-my-leftover-ca

Answer (score 4):

I went in October and left just after the ATMs were disabled in November for the switch in currency.  I went to a [Wells Fargo bank](https://www.wellsfargo.com/foreign-exchange/) and did an exchange (had to order the currency) so I had some rupees prior to going for taxi etc.
Just make sure you do not get the old currency 1,000 rupee and 500 rupee notes as they will be worthless to you. Try to get as small of notes as you can. 20 rupee notes are best. The large 2000 rupee note you will have issues also as many people do not have change for it.

http://nricafe.com/guide-carrying-currency-through-indian-airports/

I hope this helps