# Money exchange at Delhi airport, financial crisis in India?

Tags: india, exchange, del

I am planning to go to India in February 2017.

How much money can I exchange at the airport as per current regulations?

Will I have any trouble in getting hold of Indian currency at the airport?

What alternatives do I have for exchanging money while in India?

Note: India had scrapped old currency notes of 500 and 1000 rupees in November, 2016 and introduced new currency notes of 500 and 2000 denomination. However there are reports that adequate newer currency is not available and Indian central bank is modifying currency rules very frequently.

Comment: Sorry, we are not able to predict the future.

Comment: The question seems fine to me and I am voting to reopen.  Of course we cannot predict the future, but we can answer based on current conditions or any upcoming policy changes that have been announced.

Comment: @pnuts: All three questions seem fine, though perhaps they ought to be split up?

Comment: Similar to this question: http://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/83828/will-a-tourist-have-any-trouble-getting-money-from-an-atm-india-because-of-demon/83841#83841

Answer (score 6):

> I am planning to go to India in February 2017.

*Note: Due to so many regulatory changes happening since **Demonetisation of old 500 and 1000 Rupee notes**, you might have to research again for any new announcements made by the **RBI**, the day/week prior to your travel.*

> How much money can I exchange at the airport as per current regulations?

As per this [circular](https://rbi.org.in/Scripts/NotificationUser.aspx?Id=10815&Mode=0) made by the **RBI**, the *limit* for exchange of foreign currency into Indian currency is **INR 5000 per week**  at any currency exchange center be it at the airport or in cities, *provided, you submit a self-declaration that you haven't made any exchanges in that week*.

> Will I have any trouble in getting hold of Indian currency at the airport?

Not if you oblige by the [rules](http://www.cbec.gov.in/resources//htdocs-cbec/guide_for_travellers/trvler-guide_ason05feb2015.pdf) mentioned by the **CBEC**, India and *exchange restrictions* imposed by the **RBI** (mentioned above).

> What alternatives do I have for exchanging money while in India?

You can use ATMs, as the *withdrawal limit* has been increased up to **INR 10000** as per revised rules resulting in *smaller queues*.
Also since merchants and hotels have adapted to new conditions, you can use online payment wallets like *PayTM, FreeCharge, MobiKwik* to pay them. Also for travelling you can use UBER and OLA, which let you make payments using your cards and online payment wallets.

Comment: Is it possible to get one of those online payment wallets without a local SIM card however?